# How to write a Matlab program to determine the point in the square

Tags: matlab, max, point, square

How to write a Matlab program that gives 1 if a given point (x,y) is inside the square. It gives 0 if the given point (x,y) is on the boundary of the square. If give -1 if the given point (x,y) is outside the square. The square with corners (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1) and (-1,1). (Hint: you may use the function "abs" or "max")
Assume x = 0.5; y = 0.5;

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks to solve a homework question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
x = 0.5;
y = 0.5;

if  max(abs(x),abs(y)) ==1
    f = 0;
elseif max(abs(x),abs(y)) > 1 
    f = -1;
else
    f = 1;
end
```